# how pass data between fragments using LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

i want to know how pass data from one fragment to other using LiveData

i have this code and do somethings that i know but it doesnt work pls help ...

this is my first fragmetn

```
enter code here
```

class ItemDetailsfragment : Fragment() {
lateinit var viewmodel: ViewModelPassItem

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_items_page, container, false)

    val title = arguments?.getString("title")
    view.title_details_item.text = title

    val price = arguments?.getString("price")
    view.price_item_details.text = price

    val image = arguments?.getString("image")
    Picasso.get().load(image).into(view.image_items_detail)

    return view
}


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewmodel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!).get(ViewModelPassItem::class.java)


    val title: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.title_details_item)

    
    view.plus_icon_item_details.setOnClickListener {


    viewmodel.passdata(title.text.toString())

         val myfragment = Cart_Fragment()
    }

}
```

}

and this is second fragment

```
enter code here
```

class Cart_Fragment : Fragment() {

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val viewitem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_fragment, container, false)


    val choosebtn: Button = viewitem.findViewById(R.id.choose_titme_and_submit_order_btn)
    choosebtn.visibility = View.GONE


    val rl_cart = viewitem.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view_cart)
    rl_cart.visibility = View.GONE


    val navbar: BottomNavigationView = activity!!.findViewById(R.id.nav_view_bottom_main)
    navbar.visibility = View.GONE

    val homeicon: ImageButton = viewitem.home_icon_cart
    homeicon.setOnClickListener {

        activity?.let {

            val intent = Intent(requireContext(), HomeActivity::class.java)
            it.startActivity(intent)

        }
    }


    viewitem.start_shopping_in_cart.setOnClickListener {

        activity?.let {

            val intent = Intent(requireContext(), HomeActivity::class.java)
            it.startActivity(intent)


        }


    }

    return viewitem
}


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


    val viewmodel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!).get(ViewModelPassItem::class.java)


    viewmodel.pass.observe(activity!!, Observer {


        d("main", "${it.toString()}")

    })
}
```

}

and this is my ViewModel Class

```
enter code here
```

class ViewModelPassItem:ViewModel() {

```
val pass = MutableLiveData<String>()
```

fun passdata (title : String) {

```
   pass.postValue(title)
```

}
}

ok

when i click on btn to get string that i pass nothing happend ...

Answer (score 2):

In the Cart Fragment instead of passign activity lifecycleowner pass your fragments lifecycle owner. So instead of :

```
viewmodel.pass.observe(activity!!, Observer {

    Log.d("main", "${it.toString()}")

})
```

Do this :

```
viewmodel.pass.observe(this.viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    Log.d("main", "${it.toString()}")

})
```

Comment: thank's p.mathew13 worked ... but i just passed a string . i want to know how pass a ArrayList of model ... i have a Model an in it there is a Title and A Price A also one image ... how can i pass this Array list can u help with this .... i appreitiate it

Comment: Glad it helped. Please upvote and accept the answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: To solve your second requirement: Similar to your passdata method on ViewModel which takes a string as parameter create a method which takes an arraylist as parameter and call this method with your ArrayList whenever u want to pass the data. also your pass variable will be a mutablelivedata of arraylist like val pass = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<ModelClass>>()

Comment: thank's to you body ... i 'm glad to upvote your answer but for now when i click on up vote say's that tour reputation is low ... let me do it just later